# Реализация расположения 4 блоков к ряду с соединителями между ними

Tags: css, inline

Верстал один макет для набития руки и зашел в тупик. Никак не могу сделать вот этот элемент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.item {
  width: 640px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.item div.dotted {
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.item div.dotted:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
}

.item-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: -50%;
  transform: translateX(30%);
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="dotted"></div>
  <div class="dotted"></div>
  <div class="dotted"></div>
  <div class="dotted"></div>
  <div class="item-text">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit.<br> ipsum dolor sit
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit.<br> ipsum dolor sit
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit. <br> ipsum dolor sit
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit. <br> ipsum dolor sit
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вы лучший